# Proof that non-multiple odd numbers when applying coefficients will always equal 1.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

In a question that required proof by exhaustion, there are cases where any two numbers would not be multiples of each other. I came up with this statement, but I have 0 idea how to prove this:

$(\forall x \in Z, b \neq xa \land a,b \mod2 = 1) \rightarrow (\forall u \in Z, \exists v \in Z, u|a| - v|b| = 1 \lor v|b| - u|a| = 1)$

I'm not completely sure if this proof is written correctly, but the idea is how if a and b are odd and are not multiples of each other, they can always be manipulated with coefficients to equal 1.

I'm also most likely required to do it for even, even equals 2, and odd, even equals 1.

Comment: This is not true. You need the two numbers to be coprime. FOr example, there is no way to have $$u \cdot 15 + v \cdot 21 =1$$ because LHS will be always divisible by $3$.

Comment: Thanks, I missed this. In this case, would the proof by exhaustion be changed to 2 or 3 cases? The whole proof was that no matter what ua + vb was, it would be a multiple of the lowest possible value for ua + vb. Would the two cases only be values that share an GCM and values that don't share an GCM?